# mysql в java,как получить значение из столбца

Tags: java, mysql

доброго времени суток!есть такая проблема:я хочу присоединится с бд?И получить значения допустим строку,и если можно-посоветуйте книгу для работы с бд в java.

```
пароль root
имя полз root
сервер localhost
1 строка из таблицы name
2 строка из таблицы pass
3 строка из таблицы group
4 изображение(до16мб) из таблицы profile
```

Comment: Вопрос очень общий и объемный. Почитайте вот [это](http://www.javenue.info/post/java-jdbc-api).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Необходимые шаги,Следующие шаги необходимы для создания новой базы данных с помощью приложения JDBC-

1)

Import the packages:ребует , чтобы включить пакеты , содержащие классы
 JDBC , необходимые для программирования баз данных. Чаще всего, с
 помощью импорта java.sql. * Будет достаточно.

2)Register the JDBC driver:
Требует , чтобы инициализировать драйвер , так что вы можете открыть канал связи с базой данных.

3)Open a connection:
Требуется с помощью DriverManager.getConnection () метод , чтобы создать объект Connection, который представляет собой физическое соединение с сервером базы данных.

4)Execute a query:
Требуется с помощью объекта типа Заявление для построения и представления оператор SQL для выбора (т.е. выборки) записей из таблицы.

5)Extract Data:
После того, как SQL - запрос выполняется, вы можете получить записи из таблицы.

6)Clean up the environment:
Требуется явным образом закрыть все ресурсы базы данных по сравнению с полагаться на сбор мусора в JVM в.

Образец кода
Скопируйте и вставьте следующий пример в JDBCExample.java, скомпилировать и запустить следующим образом -

```
//STEP 1. Import required packages
import java.sql.*;

public class JDBCExample {

   // JDBC driver name and database URL
   static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";  
   static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/STUDENTS";

   //  Database credentials
   static final String USER = "username";
   static final String PASS = "password";

   public static void main(String[] args) {
   Connection conn = null;
   Statement stmt = null;
   try{
      //STEP 2: Register JDBC driver
      Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

      //STEP 3: Open a connection
      System.out.println("Connecting to a selected database...");
      conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);
      System.out.println("Connected database successfully...");

      //STEP 4: Execute a query
      System.out.println("Creating statement...");
      stmt = conn.createStatement();

      String sql = "SELECT id, first, last, age FROM Registration";
      ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
      //STEP 5: Extract data from result set
      while(rs.next()){
         //Retrieve by column name
         int id  = rs.getInt("id");
         int age = rs.getInt("age");
         String first = rs.getString("first");
         String last = rs.getString("last");

         //Display values
         System.out.print("ID: " + id);
         System.out.print(", Age: " + age);
         System.out.print(", First: " + first);
         System.out.println(", Last: " + last);
      }
      rs.close();
   }catch(SQLException se){
      //Handle errors for JDBC
      se.printStackTrace();
   }catch(Exception e){
      //Handle errors for Class.forName
      e.printStackTrace();
   }finally{
      //finally block used to close resources
      try{
         if(stmt!=null)
            conn.close();
      }catch(SQLException se){
      }// do nothing
      try{
         if(conn!=null)
            conn.close();
      }catch(SQLException se){
         se.printStackTrace();
      }//end finally try
   }//end try
   System.out.println("Goodbye!");
}//end main
}//end JDBCExample
```

Comment: да,но хотелось-бы просто получить ответ а потом уже разобраться как это так получилось,мне просто так легче.Да и если честно я устал уже искать.

Comment: @AseTry Дорогой Товарищ ,никогда не сдавайтесь все впросы что вы ищите есть в интернете ,просто вы неправильно состовляете вопрос ,вы задаете слишком общий вопрос ,надо по кускам ,сперва надо узнать как подключится к Базе данных ,Затем узнать как записывть туда данные ,затем как считывать ,никогда не думайте о задании обстрактно разбейте на куски .!Все получится Удачи!

Comment: спасибо!а что означает(в вашем коде)Registration это таблица или что-либо другое?

Comment: Da da regestracia eto imya tablici